# Pyodbc.connect is not connecting with created login and user

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Been stuck on this for a few days. Seen quite a few stack overflow posts on this which hasn't resolved for me and read the microsoft and pyodbc docs also but seems like my issue on this may be niche and would like some help.

**Goal:** I want to connect to sql server via a python script using `pyodbc`. I've built a `docker-compose.yml` which for the sql server image essentially points at a `Dockerfile` with `build: .`, then the dockerfile runs a `setup.sql` script is run so I create a db, user and login automatically instead of creating it every time I spin up the container.

On my laptop (checked ODBC data source admin) I have `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`, and that's why I've used in in below code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdb;UID=kafkaUser;PWD=Kafka_Us3R!;')
```

(I've seen on other posts that using `trusted_connection=yes;` should resolve this, but sadly doesn't for me.) **NOTE:** I get this error whether I use `sa`, `kafkaUser`, or `kafkaLogin` with their designated passwords. I've just copied and pasted above line after last try before resulting to posting here.

`Dockerfile:`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
WORKDIR /topics

# Env vars for sql server
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD <YourStrong!Passw0rd>
ENV MSSQL_PID Developer
ENV MSSQL_HOST localhost
ENV MSSQL_USER kafkaUser
ENV MSSQL_PASSWORD Kafka_Us3R!
ENV MSSQL_DATABASE testdb

EXPOSE 1433:1433

COPY topics/proposal-created-hl/setup.sql setup.sql
COPY topics/proposal-created-hl/setup_database.sh setup_database.sh
COPY topics/proposal-created-hl/entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ./setup_database.sh
```

`setup.sql`

```
-- MSSQL file for local testing with docker container
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'testdb' )
    CREATE DATABASE [testdb];
GO

USE [testdb]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'kafkaLogin' )
    BEGIN
        CREATE LOGIN [kafkaLogin] WITH PASSWORD = 'Kafka_Us3R!', CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
        ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [kafkaLogin];
        ALTER LOGIN [kafkaLogin] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [testdb];
        CREATE USER [kafkaUser] FOR LOGIN [kafkaLogin];
    END
GO
```

**Error:**

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'kafkaUser'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'kafkaUser'. (18456)")
```

`setup_database.sh`:

```
# Resource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309452/docker-initialize-database-tables-and-records-in-sql-server

#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Wait for database to startup 
sleep 20
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourStrong!Passw0rd>' -i setup.sql
```

I have checked this also while getting in the container (via `docker exec`) that the db, user and login have been created. So what detail am I missing here that has caused me to get this error? I tried the solutions of various posts of people coming across the same error but this hasn't resolved for me. Is there something else I need to look at?

Comment: `kafkaLogin` <> `kafkaUser`. You are using the `USER` , *not* the `LOGIN` in your Python code. If you consult the SQL Server's logs, you'll see the error tell you that no `LOGIN` with the name `kafkaUser` can be found.

Comment: In truth, as well, if the `LOGIN` is a `sysadmin`, there is no need to `CREATE` a `USER` for it in any of the databases.

Comment: I get this error whether I use `sa`, `kafkaUser`, or `kafkaLogin` with their designated passwords.

Comment: What do the SQL Server logs say is the authentication error?

Comment: Same as above, just "Login failed for user 'kafkaLogin'" or 'kafkaUser' or 'sa'

Comment: That isn't an error that the logs will have. The logs will have a more verbose error; what is that error?

Comment: Ahh sorry, you mean the docker container logs? ... Checked but nothing that shows any error at all, let alone with creating a login or user

Comment: SQL Server, by default, logs authentication errors, so I find this unlikely; the connection is certainly occurring against an instance. Where and how are you checking the SQL Server's log? Are you, by any chance, running a SQL Server instance on the main host as well as one in the docker environment?

Comment: I'm checking inside the mssql docker container. And no, not running any other instance only via docker using localhost. Is there other logs for my mssql image I can check?

Comment: What do you mean "checking in side the container"; how are you checking? *What* are you checking? Are you saying you can see *no* authentication error in `/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog`? if so, then it seems you aren't connecting to the instance you think you are.

Comment: Yeah I've checked those logs, which are also on my docker daemon. Seems to be the same logs. And yes I can see no auth error, so I guess that means I haven't connected as I thought. But if my docker container is running and I can query my testdb and query `select name from sys.database_principals` for e.g., then why isn't pyodbc connecting using any credentials?

Comment: Is sql server login enabled? 
Run: SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'   
END as [Authentication Mode]

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75474678/edit) your question to include the contents of `setup_database.sh`. Likely it's failing because it's not waiting for SQL Server to start up and accept connections, so `testdb` and your configured users never get created. Take a look at [twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app) to see how it waits and retries.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning tbh, I don't think that's it because using `select * from sys.database_principals` I can see `kafkaUser` is created as well as `kafkaLogin` from `sys.server_principals`. Added bash script anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem I was having and will leave the question open as I didn't see a similar solution to the same problem on other stack overflow posts or github solutions.

So turns out is was a docker port issue. So in my `Dockerfile` I had above, the `EXPOSE` line somehow did not actually expose the port I wanted. I had to add that into my `docker-compose.yml` file such like:

```
# This file is to be run for local testing

version: '3'

services:
  sql-server-db:
    build: .
    container_name: sqlserver
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"    # <----------------- like this
```

Then I logged into mssql locally by using `localhost, 1433` as the server name inside my `pyodbc.connection` string like so:

```
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
        'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; \
        SERVER=localhost, 1433; \
        DATABASE=testdb; \
        UID=kafkaLogin; \
        PWD=Kafka_Us3R!; \
        ENCRYPT=no' 
    )
```

Then this worked for me. I hope this helps if anyone else comes across the same issue.